# Invalid JSON error reported whenever a PointField is saved with the GooglePointFieldWidget in the Django admin

Tags: django, geojson

I am using Django 4.1 and `GooglePointFieldWidget` (from [django-map-widgets](https://github.com/erdem/django-map-widgets/tree/master)) on `PointField`s (from [django-geojson](https://github.com/makinacorpus/django-geojson)).

The widget gets displayed as it should and I'm able to change the coordinates, set a marker on the map or even type in an address. All good.

The problem is that I'm getting a validation error upon saving the object because `GooglePointFieldWidget` fills in the hidden `textarea` of the field with invalid JSON, something like

```
POINT (26.2616671966018 65.06716787213769)
```

when Django expects something like

```
{'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [26.2616671966018, 65.06716787213769]}
```

[image]

How can I solve this validation error?